# MOSS 2007 Excel Services - Show all Rows and Columns?

Tags: 2007, excel-services, navigation

We're running SharePoint 2007. Is there a way to disable the arrow navigation buttons in Excel Services and instead display all rows and columns in the worksheet so the user can use the browser scrollbars instead? Right now it only shows 75 rows at a time. We want to disable that so it shows the entire spreadsheet. Our users are very annoyed by this "feature."

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: I just figured out that you can change the max rows and columns if it is a web part, but I can't seem to figure out how to set that globally so it changes on the xlviewer.asp page.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out after some googling. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/luisbeonservices/customizing-ewa-in-the-xlviewer-aspx-page) explains how to customize the xlviewer.aspx file to set this parameter. I'm surprised Microsoft doesn't have a setting for this...